# custom button visibility list view

Tags: list-view

I have addded a custom button to list views in the Contact object. I have multiple list views but I just need to show the custom button in some of the list views and it should be hidden in the remaining lists views.

Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try with a narrow sidebar component on a home page and based on list view name you can use jquery in sidebar component to hide button for certain list views.

Comment: link not working anymore...